# C# Getting List of Directories Using TreeView Node Information

Tags: c#, treeview, nodes, descendant

I have couple of nodes in a Tree-view that user can drag to create child nodes etc.

I am using couple of methods to retrieve the parent node list:

```
private static IList<Node> BuildParentNodeList(AdvTree treeView)
    {
        IList<Node> nodesWithChildren = new List<Node>();

        foreach (Node node in treeView.Nodes)
            AddParentNodes(nodesWithChildren, node);

        return nodesWithChildren;
    }

    private static void AddParentNodes(IList<Node> nodesWithChildren, Node parentNode)
    {
        if (parentNode.Nodes.Count > 0)
        {
            nodesWithChildren.Add(parentNode);
            foreach (Node node in parentNode.Nodes)

                AddParentNodes(nodesWithChildren, node);
        }
    }
```

Then, on the parent node I use an extension method to get all the descendant nodes:

```
public static IEnumerable<Node> DescendantNodes(this  Node input)
{
        foreach (Node node in input.Nodes)
        {
            yield return node;
            foreach (var subnode in node.DescendantNodes())
                yield return subnode;
        }
    }
```

Here's a typical arrangement of my nodes:

```
Computer
  Drive F
    Movies     
    Music
      Enrique
      Michael Jackson
        Videos
```

I need a string representation of the path of every node that has child nodes.
E.g:

```
Computer\DriveF
Computer\DriveF\Movies\
Computer\DriveF\Music\
Computer\DriveF\Music\Enrique
Computer\DriveF\Music\Michael Jackson
Computer\DriveF\Music\Michael Jackson\Videos
```

I am having problem getting this exact representation using the above methods. Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Use the vendor's support channels to get help for this non-standard component.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  List<string> listPath = new List<string>();
  GetAllPaths(treeView1.Nodes[0], listPath);

  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  foreach (string item in listPath)
    sb.AppendLine(item);

  MessageBox.Show(sb.ToString());
}

private void GetAllPaths(TreeNode startNode, List<string> listPath)
{
  listPath.Add(startNode.FullPath);

  foreach (TreeNode tn in startNode.Nodes)
    GetAllPaths(tn, listPath);
}
```